# jQuery hide fails only with the HTML5 doctype

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page containing several main menus, each with submenus. In the jQuery `ready` function, the very first thing I do is `.hide()` the class subMenu (then hide the main menus, then show the first main menu).

```
<div class="menuEnt" id="mm1">
  <div class="menuText">Main Menu Entry</div>
  <div class="subMenu">
    <div class="submenuEnt" id="sm1">Submenu Entry #1</div>
    <div class="submenuEnt" id="sm2">Submenu Entry #2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works fine with `DOCTYPE HTML 4.01 Transitional`.  When I switch to `DOCTYPE html`, however, the submenus don't hide (the page comes up with the first submenu showing).  Inspecting the element, the display style attribute indeed isn't applied, and tracing through jQuery, it looks as though the subMenu class elements can't be found.

(Tested in Safari and Firefox on Mac OSX, with jQuery versions 1.8.3 and 1.11.1.)

I've fixed this by putting `display:none` in the CSS for the submenus, but given that I've come to rely on jQuery for things like this, I'm wondering how jQuery handles this differently with the change in DOCTYPE?

Comment: First off, there is no reason not to do this: if you want something hidden set it as hidden and show it when needed. So your current 'workaound' might be better anyway. Why it works like this is hard to say: you did not give us much to work with (please, next time add a complete example (but as small as possible)). I can guess it might be something like parsing of your DOM takes a bit more time. Maybe you don't gide on pageload, but you just call it randomly? Maybe it is called and the element isn't there yet?

Comment: You should really move all the hiding and showing over to CSS and only trigger a class on the menu item to show the sub menu.

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, jQuery is a bit weird when it comes to doctypes. If you've got HTML5, omit the doctype declaration altogether to have it work with jQuery. That's right, start with the `<html>` tag.

However, as already proposed in the comments, it might be better to work with a special CSS class to toggle the displaying of the element in question; instead of calling `hide`/`show`:

```js
var $obj = $('#obj'), objVisible = false;

$('#trigger').click(function(){
  $obj[objVisible ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass']('visible');
  objVisible = !objVisible;
});
```

```css
#trigger { cursor: pointer }
#obj { display: none }
#obj.visible { display: block }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='trigger'>click me</p>
<p id='obj'>I'm not visible at page load.</p>
```

Comment: Removing the DOCTYPE works!  I do plan on keeping the initial hidden state in the CSS-- it works fine and after loading the toggling works fine as well.  As I said, I'm just curious about the changed behavior... What are the repercussions of leaving off the DOCTYPE altogether?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know, at least my knowledge is not solid enough to give advice. I only knew this DOCTYPE thing because I've stumbled across it in the past, and because the jQuery mobile examples (at least back then) also didn't have a DOCTYPE declaration.

Comment: Looks like the main result of no DOCTYPE is to force quirks mode (e.g. https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/).  At least I know the lay of the land... thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Thanks for researching and posting your findings! :)